# How to retrieve element id of parent node to use within a trigger definition

Tags: css-selectors, google-tag-manager

In Google Tag Manager it is possible to trigger triggers based on css selector matching. If a html element matches the css selector, a trigger gets triggered (more details available here: http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/matches-css-selector-operator-in-gtm-triggers/)

Currently I use the following css selector matching to identify if a trigger should be triggered or not:

```
div#admin-button-id, div#admin-button-id *
```

So the first part before the comma indicates one possibility, it matches all div elements with the id admin-button-id.
The second possibilty (after the comma) matches all html elements that are children of a div element with id admin-button-id. This works, but I would prefer a version in which I would not have to duplicate div#admin-button-id. So, something like

```
div#admin-button-id *?
```

to indicate that the children are optional. Is there such a valid construct?

Comment: Can you expand your example further?

Comment: @ShannonYoung I added more details about my problem and hope it's clearer now.

Comment: For what it's worth, IDs tend to be unique. I don't know how Google Tag Manager works, but I'm sure they're still supposed to be unique in that.

Comment: Well, the IDs are definetely unique, there is only one element with the id admin-button-id. But I not only want to select the element with the id, but also all its children elements, so therefore I used the css selector with the comma that matches both.

Comment: Perhaps you could set up your trigger to use regex matching instead of CSS selector matching.

Comment: @nyuen based on https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106961?hl=en I think the regex matching is supposed to be used primarily for urls? I'm not sure how that would work, for example if i click on an element, I can regex on the following input: [object HTMLDivElement]. But that is not enough to distinguish various html elements, especially since I don't have access on its parent elements.

Comment: You can build a trigger that does a regex match on the Click ID of the element clicked. Alternatively you could write a custom JavaScript variable that could do the same thing or more, and gives you more control over the various DOM elements, including parents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on suggestions from @nyen I came up with the following solution:

I have to deal with the following markup code (unnecessary css classes ommited):

```
<div id="admin-button-id">
    <span>
        <span>Administration</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

It is possible to click on various parts of this button, either the innermost span, the intermediate span or the outer div. But only the outer div includes an id which I can use to match against in my GTM trigger. So within GTM I created a user-defined variable called 'calculatedClickId' of type 'Custom JavaScript'. The custom function searches for the id in the dom tree in the outward direction (from the innermost span to the outher div):

```
function() {
  if ({{Click Element}}.id != "") {
    return {{Click Element}}.id;
  }
  if ({{Click Element}}.parentNode.id != "") {
    return {{Click Element}}.parentNode.id;
  }
  return {{Click Element}}.parentNode.parentNode.id;
}
```

The `{{Click Element}}` is the html element that is provided by GTM. So now it doesn't matter where within my html element a click occurs, the variable `calculatedClickId` is always set to the id of the outer div.

This allows me to use the variable `calculatedClickId` within my trigger configuration easily:

[image]

I'm aware that the custom javascript method is not bulletproof (yet) and might be refined further, but this solution is an improvement over the css selector method.

Comment: It's a shame this simple requirement is not part of tag manager condition "CSS parent contains" . But nice workaround.