# GA/GTM Returning <a> ID from clicks on images or text within an anchor tag?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

When presented with the following structure...

```
<a id="link-flickr-vs-team" href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/...">
    <img src="images/gallery1.jpg" alt="thumb">
    <i class="fa fa-camera-retro" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    Descriptive text here
</a>
```

How do I set up my trigger to account for the click on the image or text. Right now I can't seem to get it to register on the image. My current trigger settings are...

```
Click - All Elements
Some Clicks
Click Element, matches CSS selector, a*
```

... and my  Tag Configuration is...

```
UA Google Analytics
Track Type: Event
Category: Flickr
Action: Click
Label: {{Click Element}}
Etc...
```

The event label returns `[object HTMLImageElement]` but I need it to return the id from the `<a>` but using `Click ID` returns `(not set)` when click the image, only the text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve element id of parent node to use within a trigger definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024126/how-to-retrieve-element-id-of-parent-node-to-use-within-a-trigger-definition)

Comment: Thanks for posting, that link helped a lot.